# Solve $\begin{cases} (x-y)^2=3-2x-2y\\ y(x-y+1)=x(y-x+1) \end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $\begin{cases} (x-y)^2=3-2x-2y \\ y(x-y+1)=x(y-x+1) \end{cases} $

$\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases} x^2-2xy+y^2=3-2x-2y\\xy-y^2+y=xy-x^2+x \end{cases}$

Simplifying the second equation:

$\Leftrightarrow x^2-y^2=x-y \\ \Leftrightarrow 
(x+y)(x-y)=x-y\\ \Leftrightarrow x+y=1$

The first equation becomes:

$\Leftrightarrow x^2-2xy+y^2=3-2(x+y)=1\\ \Leftrightarrow (x-y)^2=1 \\ \Leftrightarrow x-y=\pm1$

Hence:
$\begin{cases} x+y=1\\x-y=\pm1 \end{cases} \Rightarrow x=1,y=0$ or $x=0,y=1$ which are the correct answers.

However the problem is $x=\dfrac{3}{4}, y=\dfrac{3}{4}$ is also given as an answer. But I can't see how its possible for me to derive this answer from the given equations. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your second step on simplifying the second equation you assume $x\neq y$ (as you divide by $x-y$). Try solving the system of equations when assuming $x=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

$$(x+y)(x-y)=x-y \Leftrightarrow x+y=1.$$

Instead,

$$(x-y)(x+y-1)=0.$$

Two cases are possible: $x+y=1$ or $x=y$.

The first case is done by you. The second case turns the first equation into $$0=3-4x.$$

Hence the $$x=y=3/4.$$

It’s always a bad idea to divide by something that may be equal to $0$ ($x-y$ in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake when simplifying the second equation.

$(x+y)(x-y) = x-y \Leftrightarrow x+y = 1$ is only true if $x-y \neq 0$.

I also don't get how you got $(x-y)^2 = 1$ from the first equation. The first equation simplifies to $y = x \pm 2 \sqrt{1-x}-1$. From there you get $(0, 1)$, $(1, 0)$ and $(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4})$